# R recommendation Grid Search Optimization

Tags: r, optimization, grid-search

I have a self-developed function foo(a,b) taking two Parameters and Returns a value that I want to minimize. I know that a is between 0 and 1 but b is unconstrained.

Do you have some recommoendation, which package / function I can use to find the Minimum depending on my Parameters a and b?

I can use gridSearch(foo, a, b) (NMOF package) but this is just brute-force.

Thank you for the discussion!

Answer (score 2):

`optim()` is a base R function that will do what you want. It implements a bunch of optimization routines. Some methods such as `L-BFGS-B` also allow for box constraints if you know the range of the parameters.

If this does not fit your needs, there are lots of packages offering more optimization algorithms, have a look at the [CRAN task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html).